# Simple HTML DOM css

Tags: php, css

I am using Simple HTML DOM to get content from a website. However some of the images do not display because they are set as backdroung images from an external so I have called this in also.

However the image dose not have the full path.

```
<style>    
div.spriteImgSmall { background: url(/images/css_sprites/film_sprites/smallimages_sprite.jpg); } 
    div.spriteImgSmall_17826 { background-position: -0px -0px; width: 86px; height: 64px; }
</style>
```

There are no head or body tags as this is part of a facebook app. How could I use Simple HTML DOM to add on the base url to the path?

Comment: If they are relative paths, why not parse the url you're getting them from?

Comment: I am new to this, sorry. I do not understand, would you have some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM deals with structured HTML, however what you've got there is CSS, which for DOM is just unstructured text. So probably your best approach would be:

1. Parse HTML DOM, find style tags
2. Take contents of the style tag  by using something like `(string)$dom->style`
3. Parse the content with `preg_match()`, looking for `url(blah-blah)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was working on preg_match and found the solution when I stumbled on the a way to do it through the simple html dom. Funny I searched this whole site and found nothing before asking.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329499/convert-a-relative-url-to-an-absolute-url-with-simple-html-dom