# How to export specific A tags from a file.[html] in PHP

Tags: php, html

i have a html file and some A tags in it.

i need to export some specific A tags from it.

here is the whole html file [HTML_FILE_LINK](https://www.tinymusic.net/tgbot/stackover.txt)

i want to extract only `dl/l/Lucy.2014.Dubbed.Audio.TinyMoviez_co(Onyx).mp3?hash=27bd643109ad5f992c28e10a33afe8dc_159484_26806_3`

and the other ones like this.

how can i do this in php?

i have tried this : [how to get a list of links in a webpage in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314936/how-to-get-a-list-of-links-in-a-webpage-in-php) but didnt work.

i really need this if anyone could answer i would appreciate .

Comment: Why doesn't this answer work? There's a complete script, which does what you ask for, and a link http://stackoverflow.com/q/4461105/1741542 to yet another question with even simpler solutions.

Comment: "and the other ones like this" -- what does this mean?  How do you know which tags you want?

Comment: @OlafDietsche tnx. but it exports all the A tag from the page. i only need some of them which is linked to text "لینک مستقیم ویژه" . is there any way to only export the ones that are linked to above text?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter all the A tags linked to text "لینک مستقیم ویژه"

Comment: @EatPeanutButter only the link of the text " Ù„ÛŒÙ†Ú© Ù…Ø³ØªÙ‚ÛŒÙ… ÙˆÛŒÚ˜Ù‡ " in that html file .

Comment: In your question, you want to extract `dl/l/Lucy.2014.Dubbed.Audio.TinyMoviez_co(Onyx).mp3?hash=27bd643109ad5f992c28e10a33afe8dc_159484_26806_3`, and in a comment you want to extract "لینک مستقیم ویژه". Which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on this answer from [Parse Website for URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4461298/1741542) gives already all `a` tags

```
$code = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);
$links = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element) {
    if ($element->hasAttribute('href')) {
        $links[] = $element->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

---

But you want only specific links, so you must check [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) it satisfies some condition. Extract all relevant parts and see if it matches

```
$text = $element->nodeValue;
$link = $element->getAttribute('href');
if ($text == "لینک مستقیم ویژه") {
    echo "$link\n";
}
```

---

Putting everything together gives

```
$code = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element) {
    if ($element->hasAttribute('href')) {
        $text = $element->nodeValue;
        $link = $element->getAttribute('href');
        if ($text == "لینک مستقیم ویژه") {
            echo "$link\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted. thanks man. i cant give +1 because of my reputation sry.